# Python Import Error - No module

Tags: python, flask

I'm sorry this is basic. I've followed a fairly simple tutorial and get this error when trying to run flask locally:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/james/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/james/Documents/GitHub/flask-app-blueprint/project/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'
```

However in the same environment when I ran pip list it tells me I have that module: Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.2

```
(venv) (base) james flask-app-blueprint % pip3 install flask-sqlalchemy
Requirement already satisfied: flask-sqlalchemy in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=0.10 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask-sqlalchemy) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy>=0.8.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask-sqlalchemy) (1.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->flask-sqlalchemy) (2.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->flask-sqlalchemy) (0.24)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.14 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->flask-sqlalchemy) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->flask-sqlalchemy) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10->Flask>=0.10->flask-sqlalchemy) (2.0.1)
```

On top of that the code I have in my file looks correct based on what I see:

```
# IMPORTS
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

Where might I have gone wrong?

Comment: You're in the wrong virtualenv.

Comment: How do I set the right one?

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that when you run your flask script, the environment that it uses (anaconda) doesn't have the `flask_sqlalchemy` package installed, which makes the script fail, but when you check whether it is or it isn't installed, you do so in the virtual environment `venv` where it is indeed installed.

Comment: How do I set the right venv?